# Update existing plain password to encrypted for OAUTH

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, owin

I am developing a .net application with OAUTH(OWIN) mechanism, and going to connect existing database with this application.

I have developed a sample application using the tutorial given in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Now I need to migrate existing database table contents into OAuth authentication tables.

One main problem in existing database is the password values are in plain text.

To login in exisitng accounts the passwords to need to be updated to recognizable by OAuth application.

for this, i want to know which encryption method is used in OAuth by default.

I'm using MSSQL server for Database.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't this be left to you to decide? If you derive OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider and implement GrantResourceOwnerCredentials in that way that you query a database by using EntityFramework, you can choose how to keep passwords.